# `ls M*` displayes the subdirectory

Tags: bash, ls, subdirectory, glob

I run the commands and receive results as:

```
    $ ls M*
    ManagerGit
    $ ls m*
    ManagerGit
```

The problem is that dir `ManagerGit` isn't on the the current directory,
Try the command:

```
    $ ls | grep -i 'manage'
    Manager
```

It's subdirectory of dir Manage

```
    tree -L 2
  ...
    ├── Manager
    │   └── ManagerGit
  ...
```

What's the mechanism behind it?

Comment: Replace `ls M*` with `echo ls M*` to see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the shell expands `ls M*` to `ls Manager` - i.e. list the contents of the directory called `Manager`.

`ls` doesn't know how to filter.  I suggest you do something like this:

```
find . -depth 1 -name 'M*'
```

Answer (score 1):

I always find `ls -d M*` is quicker and easier to write (rather than `find ...`) where `-d` does the following:

```
-d, --directory
    list directories themselves, not their contents
```